# How can I give my input field the value of the last checked checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to have my input box always show the value of the last checked checkbox.

This is my try but it is not working:

```
<input type="text" name="status" value="blue" class="status"/>

<div class="checkbox"><input type='checkbox' value='blue' checked/> blue</div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type='checkbox' value='green' checked/> green</div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type='checkbox' value='yellow' checked/> yellow</div>

$("input").change(function(){
     $('.status').val($('input:checkbox:last'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4csbmtad/

Maybe you have a suggestion for me!

---

I am making an update I forgot: If nothing is checked, then I need to display the word "nothing selected" in the input field

Comment: What do you mean by `last checked checkbox`? explain.

Comment: I mean if `blue` and `green` is checked and `yellow` is unchecked, then display in the input field `green`. If only `blue` is checked, display `blue`. If `blue` and `yellow` is checked and `green` is unchecked, then display `yellow`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use selector as `:checkbox:checked:last`

1. **[`:checkbox`](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)** for getting checkboxes
2. **[`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)** filtering checked checkbox from that
3. **[`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** getting the last checked
4. Trigger **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** event to set value on page load

.

```js
$("input").change(function() {
  var $chk = $(':checkbox:checked:last');
  $('.status').val($chk.length ? $chk.val() : 'nothing is selected');
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="status" value="blue" class="status" />

<div class="checkbox">
  <input type='checkbox' value='blue' checked/>blue</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type='checkbox' value='green' checked/>green</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type='checkbox' value='yellow' checked/>yellow</div>
```

**Update :** Check **[`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/)** property of selector to check at least one is checked or not.

Comment: if i checked all then unchecked 1st and checked , result must be 1st (blue)??

Comment: @akash :  in that case just need `this.value`

Answer (score 3):

You can use with this.

```
   $("input").on("change",function(){
     var result = $('input:checked').length==0?"nothing selected":$(this).val();
     $('.status').val(result);
   });
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egvrcn/4csbmtad/5/)

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the last checked checkbox on load and change: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4csbmtad/3/)

```
   function lastChecked() {
        $('.status').val($('input:checkbox:checked').last().val());
    }
    //Get value on load
    lastChecked();

    //Get value on change
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        lastChecked();
    });
```

Comment: if i checked all then unchecked 1st and checked , result must be 1st (blue)??

Comment: I don't think I understand. It will show the last checked checkbox. If none are checked, it won't show anything.